Should Psalm 104 be read as a commentary on Genesis 1 or vice versa?
Should Psalm 104 be read as a commentary on Genesis 1 or vice versa?
What does scholarly consensus say about when Psalm 104 and Genesis 1 was written?

What's the connection that you see between Gen 1 & Psa 104?

There are so many questions here I hardly know where to begin.  Let me try to address a few of them.
Authorship of Ps 104 - not stated and unknown.  Therefore, date of composition unknown.
Authorship of Gen 1 - Traditionally, Moses about 1500 BC (much debated in some quarters.)
Relationship of Ps 104 to Gen 1
There is no broad literary structural parallel between Ps 104 and Gen 1.  However there are two points in common:

Ps 104:19 the sun and moon marking seasons, compare Gen 1:14;
Ps 104:20 describes darkness and light in parallel to Gen 1:2, 3

BUT there are numerous topics in Ps 104 not covered in Gen 1.  Indeed, almost all of the rest of the psalm covers material not in Gen 1 such as:

Ps 104:2a - God clothed with splendor and majesty
Ps 104:2b - God stretches out the heavens like a tent
Ps 104:3, 4 have no parallel in Gen 1
Ps 104:5 - God set the earth on its foundations
Ps 104:14-18 describes the functioning of the natural world - this is absent in Gen 1.
etc

Thus, Ps 104 is simply a celebration of the great and awesome works of God the creator and sustainer of the natural world.  It is the kind of Psalm that Job might have written; but we do not know who composed the Psalm.
